# Is there a way to get the title of a cross-origin sandboxed iframe's document?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

I am making a basic web browser, written in HTML. I'd like to access the title of the document, so that you can see it like a tab in a normal browser. Usually, you can use `iframe.contentDocument.title`, but my iframe is cross-origin and sandboxed so this doesn't seem to work. Is there a way that you can access the title anyway, or is this impossible?

Here's an example:

```js
const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
const span = document.querySelector("span");

document.querySelector("iframe").addEventListener("load", function() {
  const title = iframe.contentDocument.title; // contentDocument is null
  span.innerText = title;
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

iframe {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title: <span id="title"></span></h1>
<iframe src="https://www.bing.com" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

Comment: I doubt it's possible. There's very little about the content of a cross-origin iframe that's accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access it directly, however, if you can add JS to the page in the iFrame, then you can use [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) between the two pages.

Every page in your iframe would need to add the following.

```
top.postMessage(document.title, '*')
```

Then in the parent page you need to receive the message.

```js
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  alert(event.data)
}, false)
```